# zsh function: bad substitution

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I have written the following function in my `.zshrc` file:

```sh
myfunc () 
{
    folderpath="${find . -type d -name myfolder}"
    package="${basename $PWD}"
    ln -fs "$path" "$HOME"/links/"$package"/myfolder
}
```

After `source ~/.zshrc` and running `myfunc` at the command line I get the following error:

```
myfunc:2: bad substitution
```

Why?

Comment: Where do you actually use `folderpath` in this function? In `zsh`, I wouldn't even bother with `find`: use `**/myfolder/` instead.

Comment: In ZSH you want to use parenthesis () not curlies {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `zsh`, you can also simply write

```
package=$PWD:t
```

No command substitution needed.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for piping the output of a command into a variable in zsh is:

```
package=$(basename $PWD)
```

Comment: That's the correct syntax in most shells. (`ksh` being a notable exception, where `${...}` lets you run a (shell) command in the current shell instead of a subshell).